# Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details

Tags: unity-game-engine

I got following error while making apk file from unity. I set minimum API level=19 and target 24. because I build a apk for Gear VR and I have Samsung S7 Edge.

> CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests. See the
>   Console for more details.  C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M
>   -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Users\saad asghar\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -
>
> stderr[ Error:Invalid command manifmerger ] stdout[
>
> ] exit code: 64 UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String
>   javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand,
>   Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String
>   javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand,
>   Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Comment: Check if there is only one `android.manifest` file in your project

Comment: May be there should be space between "-D file.encoding=" and between "-D com.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir".

Comment: you mean that there is mistakes in sdk paths which i set i unity? please elaborate your answer i don't understand  this "-D file.encoding=" and between "-D com.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir"

Comment: there are two manifest files one is android.manifest-main and other is android.manifest present in androidlibrary/ovrplugin                                        help me what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

The error happens due to this [Unity bug](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-build-fails-when-the-latest-android-sdk-tools-25-dot-3-1-version-is-used) (related to the latest Android SDK tools version).

You can see in the error message that the "manifmerger" tool returns an error code (64):

> stderr[ Error:Invalid command manifmerger ] stdout[
>
> ] exit code: 64

The bug is fixed in the latest Unity (beta) version. There is a workaround, as described on that page:

> Workaround for the customers.
>
> 1. just open https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
> 2. scroll down to the bottom of that page
> 3. go to downloads
> 4. scroll down to the bottom of that page
> 5. find Windows "[tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip)" download and unzip it
> 6. or, on mac: find MacOSX "[tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip)" download and unzip it.
> 7. In the SDK path replace the tools folder.

This is a quote from the issuetracker page. I've added direct links to the downloads, since they seem to be missing from the Android website.

Comment: thanks for reply! i already tried this solution but still get same errors , if i download unity beta version so this fix my problems ?

Comment: This should fix your issues. I've done this for countless developers as part of my gig: https://www.fiverr.com/lysergide/fix-android-build-issues-in-your-unity3d-project
you should not use the beta version (haven't tested it myself, so i am not sure it fixes the issue).

Comment: Thank you so much! you save my time , it works after replace the tools  actually before i did something wrong. thanks man for help

Comment: great to hear. mark this as the answer so it can help others

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rise up your minimum api level, usually when there is high diffrence between target devices and minimum api level Unity fail to merge android manifests.

I hope this will work your problem :)

Comment: thanks for reply! suggest me what minimum API level should i set?

Comment: it is not worked for me after i raise minimum API level to 23 still get same errors .

Comment: Is your skd ndk and jdk updated? I may cause the problem

Comment: i think i get errors because of 2 manifest files in my project because i use OVR plugin one is manifest main and other is manifest only. and i don't install ndk because i read that there is no need. if you say i install  ndk also, and yes sdk and jdk is update till now

Comment: i use unity 5.6.1f1. is there any issue in this version?

Comment: @GeetaParshotam you dont need ndk thats right and i didnt come across any problem on 5.6 using two manifest is the problem i think.

Comment: so now how can i resolve this ? any idea

Comment: @GeetaParshotam well you can try to delete one of the manifest, it probably wont work but there is still chance  if it doesnt work you can delete and instal sdk from begining and reset your unity settings it would solve the problem

Comment: thanks. i will try this solution also

Comment: @GeetaParshotam ok let me know if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much guys for help!

finally i make apk file by doing the following steps.

1 just open https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
2 scroll down to the bottom of that page
go to downloads
scroll down to the bottom of that page
3 find Windows "tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip" download and unzip it
4 or, on mac: find MacOSX "tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip" download and unzip it.
5 In the SDK path replace the tools folder.